# How do I get the content of the message from its message link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
let Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = { 
    name: "request",
    aliases: ["req","report"],
    permissions: ["MANAGE_NICKNAMES"],
      /**
   * @param {Discord.Message} message
   * @param {Array} args$
   */
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (args.length >= 2) {
            args.shift();
        } else reason = 'No reason provided'
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("Message link content: ")
    }
```

I'm trying to make this bot display the content of a message from its message link. A user would copy the message link of a message that someone sent, then use this command, which should display what the message says.

Is this possible, and how do I achieve this? I've tried to find a tutorial but didn't seem to come out.

Comment: A message link contains the ids (in order) for the guild, channel, and message. So that would be your way in. First get the guild (if possible) then the channel (if possible) then the message (if possible).

Comment: no.. the user is gonna send the message link, and I just have to get the data from that.

Comment: Still sounds exactly like what I gave the advice for.

Comment: how do we get the message, since message links are numbers & guild/channels have ids so that's easy, but how do we find the message?

Comment: As guilds/channels have ids, messages have ids too, so that's also easy. ;) Edit your question and make it more clear, to improve your chances of getting a decent answer. I am quite confused and don't really understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: yea it's kinda confusing here, do you have discord? I can explain alot better there with an example that might explain further

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839723/how-to-get-content-of-the-message-from-message-link#comment121660029_68839723) comment from [@0x464e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813732/0x464e), you just need to split the IDs. This is a function that could work:

```js
async function messageByLink(link) {
  const ids = link.slice("https://discord.com/channels/".length).split("/")
  const [, channelId, messageId] = ids
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelId)
  const message = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId)
  if(!message) throw new Error("Message could not be found")
  return message
}
```

And then call it with this:

```js
//async function
//link is a valid message link
const foundMsg = await messageByLink(link);
console.log(foundMsg)
```

Comment: how do we get the content inside after

Comment: @JoonyWoony [`foundMsg.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)

Comment: so, the link inside is going to my arguement where I insert the message link right? So like this:
messageByLink(link) <-- that link is going to be where i put the message link inside right?

Comment: Yes. You have to call it with the message link as the parameter.

Comment: okay, how do we get the message link's author, so the user that posted the message.

Comment: `foundMsg` is the MESSAGE OBJECT which has `foundMsg.content`, `foundMsg.author`, etc.